# Regular Expression to match specific pattern (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

Given the following text string:

```
groups:label(test:one):items:idx(0):value
```

I want to end up with the following matches:

```
groups
test:one
items:idx(0):value
```

I'm very close with this expression, but it's still not exact and I'm going in circles:

```
([^:]+):label\((.+)\):(.+)
```

Please help with your expertise. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make inner `(.+)` that is the one inside `\(` and `\)` as non-greedy,

```
([^:]+):label\((.+?)\):(.+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eX5nD5/1)

**OR**

USe a negated character class instead of `.+?`,

```
([^:]+):label\(([^()]*)\):(.+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eX5nD5/2)

`[^()]` Would matches any character but not of `(` or `)` zero or more times.

Comment: Thank you! Both seem to work great. I've chosen to use the first version, as it is easier to read. :)